# React.js with Ag-grid: How to disable dragging in AgGridReact component?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, ag-grid-react

To preface this, I'm new to programming (<3 months) and I'm still learning basic concepts and terminology; forgive me if I seem obtuse. At the moment, I'm using an ag-grid component for the first time. My return statement has the following:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input placeholder="Description" name="description" value={todo.description} onChange={inputChanged} />
      <input placeholder="Date" name="date" value={todo.date} onChange={inputChanged}/>
      <input placeholder="Status" name="status" value={todo.status} onChange={inputChanged}/>
      <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
      <div className="ag-theme-material" style={{ height: 600, width: 600, margin: 'auto' }}>
        <AgGridReact
           rowData={todos}>
          <AgGridColumn field="description" sortable={true} filter={true}></AgGridColumn>
          <AgGridColumn field="date" sortable={true} filter={true}></AgGridColumn>
          <AgGridColumn field="status" sortable={true} filter={true}></AgGridColumn>
        </AgGridReact>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've been tasked with preventing the drag and drop behavior of the ag-grid component. I was given the official https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/ documentation to refer to, and I found the `rowDrag` property. I've tried to implement it as `rowDrag={false}` in the AgGridReact component, and separately into AgGridColumn, but neither method has worked. I've also searched this issue on Google, and found a few other methods that require making a whole new method for the draggability, but I think it might not be what's being sought in this exercise.

I feel dumb being stuck on this simple thing. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stop the dragging of columns then add the property
`suppressMovable=true` to all the columns. So something like this

```
<AgGridColumn field="date" sortable={true} filter={true} suppressMovable={true}></AgGridColumn>
```

You can also add this to specific columns to make them non-draggable but still you can switch its position with columns that are draggable.

`rowDrag` is false by default, so if you make it true then your rows will become draggable (I don't know if this works in community version)

you can refer this part-
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-moving/#suppress-movable